# Build asimple c++ static library of ios(for unity), but cannot find the .a file

Tags: c++, ios, unity-game-engine

As the title mentioned, using macos 12.

example.hpp

```
extern "C"{

int summation();

}
```

example.cpp

```
#include "example.hpp"

extern "C"{

int summation()
{
    return 10;
}

}
```

Then I create an Xcode project->static lib, add example.hpp and example.cpp, configure the build phase to ios only. Click on build, the xcode tell me "build succeeded", but I cannot find any .a file, even in the Xcode/DerivedData/*.

This is the first time I try to build c++ plugin for unity on ios platform, please forgive my ignorance if any.

Edit : I search the .a file shown in the full path(Image 00) but cannot find anything, color of the plugin is red color, weird

[image: Image 00]

Comment: Check the Build Report... I just created a project from scratch, as per your post, and selected Build --- this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdhv0.png and I find the file `/Volumes/ramdisk/DerivedData/MyTestLib-hiokizibxicwgjdaosereekobfss/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMyTestLib.a`

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, checked, but cannot find the .a file.

Comment: A little confusing... your post says *"configure the build phase to iOS only"* but your image shows "Destination My Mac"?

Comment: @DonMag At firsst I build it with mac + ios(forgot to switch off mac), maybe old settings cause this weird issue, checking, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple, I create a new project, add the example.hpp and example.cpp into the project, set build target to ios only, click build, then the .a file is generated, I don't know why this happen, maybe some manipulation ruin the settings.